# ORA-12154 when connecting using tns alias

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tnsnames, ora-12154

I installed Oracle 11.2 on a Win7x64 laptop and almost everything works fine. One thing I don't understand, however. I can connect to the sample HR schema with:

```
sqlplus hr/password
```

but not with:

```
sqlplus hr/password@orcl
```

I get an `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`.

I found this out by accident, as I was expecting the second option to be correct. Why can I leave out the TNS alias? I'm an Oracle beginner but when I connect to other environments, the TNS alias is required or I can't make a connection.

I have the following in my `tnsnames.ora`:

```
LISTENER_ORCL = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)))
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CLRExtProc)(PRESENTATION = RO)))

ORCL, DUMMY = (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
```

I know for sure it's being used because both `tnsping orcl` and `tnsping dummy` are ok. Can someone explain this to me?

**UPDATE 1**: The output of `lsnrctl status` is the following:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                11-NOV-2012 00:43:22
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 15 min. 53 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Ronald\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\app\ronald\diag\tnslsnr\Ronald-PDC\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

The result of `SELECT name FROM v$database` is one database: `ORCL`.

**UPDATE 2**: Output of `tnsping orcl` (formatted for readability).

```
Used parameter files:
C:\app\Ronald\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
OK (20 msec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually create a database instance named ORCL?

Check out the actual name of your database with the command

```
lsnrctl status
```

This should tell you what services the listener knows about, which is what you're talking to when connecting with the @ syntax. The reason you can connect without the @ORCL is that in that case you're using interprocess communication (IPC) and bypassing the listener, because the database is on the same computer as your SQL*Plus client session.

You can also find out the database name when you connect in the first example with this:

```
SELECT name FROM v$database;
```

EDIT:

Try the EZConnect syntax and see if that works:

```
sqlplus user/pw@localhost/ORCL
```

Keep in mind that `TNSPING` doesn't do anything besides contact the listener - it doesn't verify the database can be accessed.

One more thing: It looks like maybe TCP isn't a configured protocol for the listener? check  your listener.ora file (in the same directory as your tnsnames.ora file). The entry for LISTENER should look something like this:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

My `TNSPING` output looks a bit different in one line near the start of output:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)))
```

Comment: I added some extra info to my question. The listener seems to be working ok so I still don't see why it doesn't work with the @ syntax. Or does a localhost session simply not work over tcp?

Comment: It should work fine - it works for me, with localhost as the hostname. I modified your tnsnames entry for my system, it works, no syntax errors. Is that the only entry in your tnsnames file? No leading blanks in front of the alias names? The listener is pretty picky about syntax errors in this file.

Comment: The EZConnect syntax works. My LISTENER entry looks exactly like yours. I added the TNSPING output to my question and my entire tnsnames. Don't spend too much time on this.. I can connect to my database, I just don't understand why it doesn't work with the @ syntax.